# How to keep temp tables and variables on mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, pdo, mysqli

In my webapp I have the html Interface (with JS - Angular Module) and I work with data from mysql database. I load data using async request to PHP script, where I use PDO persistent connection, but when the request finishes, the temp tables and variables are lost... How I can keep these? I need to use them in another request.. I use it in stored procedures.

Comment: why you tagged angular here?

Comment: and it's tagged `mysqli` _and_ `pdo` - which one is it - mysqli or PDO_mysql?

Comment: Temp tables and vars can only be accessed in the same request. At the end of the request, they're gone. Can't you create a persistent table with the name 'temp' or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use temporary tables. They are *meant* do die on connection close.

This is your second attempt to ask a question, but still inappropriate one. What you have to ask is to describe your business goal and ask for the proper tool. It can be Memcached or Sphinx or something else. But apparently temporary tables are not a solution.